# Could not determine java version from '9.0.1'

Tags: java, android, gradle, bintray

Trying upload project to `bintray` and just get error:

`Could not determine java version from '9.0.1'.`

I read that it's grade bug and it fixed in upper versions, I tried
change `gradle` version to `4.2.1`, but get another error:

> Gradle sync failed: No such property: FOR_RUNTIME for class:
>   org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage           Consult IDE log for more details
>   (Help | Show Log) (571ms)

**Gradle properties:**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.2.1-all.zip
```

**Build gradle project**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.51'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta7'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: show `build.gradle` (Project)

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya done

Comment: use `gradle-3.3-all.zip`

Comment: downgrade version `tools.build:gradle:2.3.3`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya can I solve that without downgrade?

Comment: I don't know. May be bug

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should also delete Java JDK. Just run the following:

1. cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
2. sudo rm -rf jdk1

Now check typing 'java' in your terminal.

For more references you can look here: https://www.howtogeek.com/230145/how-to-uninstall-java-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: Isn't there an alternative way which will use Java from Android Studio Contents directory?

Comment: @RajanikantDeshmukh `PATH=$PATH:/opt/android-studio/jre/bin` works for me. Add that to your `.bashrc` or `.profile`. Adapt it to wherever you've placed the Android Studio files.

Answer (score 36):

This issue was in gradle version lower than `4.3`, so update your gradle.properties  to `4.3` or above:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.3-all.zip
```

**Why this error occur?**:
Because of you have different *JDK* on your system than your android-studio *JDK* version.

Therefore your *JDK* should be compatible with each other, and by following this way you can manage that:

`File` -> `Other settings` -> `Default project structure`

[image]

You can use embedded *JDK* or use your own.

---

Also you may have some issues with `terminal`, and that's belong to a conflict between your multiple *JDK*.

Solution worked with me is to uninstall the java 9 *JDK*.

Comment: I was using Java JDK 9 with Gradle 4.1 when I got this error. Switching to Gradle version 4.3 solved the error.

Comment: I solved the problem making the change in gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties. I'm using IntellijIDEA/Android Studio. Ref: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html

Comment: i have Gradle 4.4.1 changed distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4.1-bin.zip and still have the error.

Comment: I used `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4-bin.zip` and the problem had gone.

Answer (score 26):

I had this problem on macOS and I solved it by:

Removing the too new java jdk

```
brew cask uninstall java
```

And installing an older one

```
brew tap caskroom/versions
brew cask install java8
```

All this handled via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)

Comment: I got this one `Error: Cask 'java8' is unavailable: No Cask with this name exists. `

Comment: @PaulaKristin Perhaps you need to run this first `brew tap caskroom/versions`

Comment: I found the solution by making my JAVA_HOME on mac to be the same as where my android studio java is located and it solved this issue

Comment: This particular error was solved as Paula suggested (pointing to the Android studio JRE). But boy is it painful to upgrade or try and build from the command line! :(

Comment: @StephenMcCormick Honestly, that is a hacky solution. Do you mean that *this particular error* was *only solvable* with the hacky AS JRE method? The phrasing makes it a bit unclear if the answer worked or not.

Comment: @E.Sundin There may be another solution but I could not find it. By using a different JRE than Android Studio I was receiving that error (and others) and could not find a way to make it work both on the command line and in the IDE without pointing my JAVA_HOME to the same version. If you know a different solution I would be willing to give it a try.

Comment: This is the quickest way to install JDK.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the error was

> Could not determine java version from '10'.

I went to preferences in Unity (edit > preferences in windows or Unity > preferences in MAC), external tools, JDK dir and changed went up a couple of levels. I was using JDK 10, but changed to the folder of JDK 8 and this solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

just tried to build with Gradle 4.3, against JDK 9.0.1 -
this might possibly function in Android Studio (because the bundled JDK is an elder version), but not when building with Jenkins 2.89.2 (which seems to not support the JDK 9.0.1 yet, literally complaining `Could not determine java version from '9.0.1'`). bintray might also build with Jenkins, because the error message is somewhat identical.

downgrading to JDK 8 in `gradle.properties` fixed the issue for me:

```
org.gradle.java.home=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_152
```

combined with `gradle-wrapper.properties`:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need to use local gradle distribution
Eg : In IntelliJ go to File->settings->Build,Execution,Deployment->Build Tools->Gradle then update the "Use local gradle distribution" as shown in image.

[settings window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hjSg.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your files under JDK are accessible. I had same issue because my process was not able to access my JDK files due to proxy issue. Then i changed my JDK path. It worked.