# How to resolve exception in react-native : What went wrong: Could not determine java version from '9.0.1'

Tags: android, exception, react-native, runtime-error, build.gradle

This work for me:

**Edit the file /android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties and update the last line with:**

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.3-rc-2-all.zip`

So i update the `gradle` version used for project dependencies.

Comment: Gradle 4.3 is long released, why would you use a release candidate version? Btw. the current version is 4.4.1.

Comment: Please send me updated url and help me out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not determine java version from '9.0.1'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46893768/could-not-determine-java-version-from-9-0-1)

Comment: replace the `4.3-rc2` by `4.3`.