# Could not determine Java version 9.0.4

Tags: android

I am a new developer and have recently installed Android studio 3.0 on my Windows 10 device with Java JDK version 9.0.4 installed but after installing, the app shows a problem:

```
could not determine java version 9.0.4
```

and shows a Gradle sync problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/46893768/9130109

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not determine java version from '9.0.1'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46893768/could-not-determine-java-version-from-9-0-1)

Answer (score 0):

This issue was in gradle version lower than 4.3, so update your gradle.properties to 4.3 or above:

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip

Why this error occur?: Because of you have different JDK on your system than your android-studio JDK version.

Therefore your JDK should be compatible with each other, and by following this way you can manage that:

File -> Other settings -> Default project structure
[image]

You can use embedded JDK or use your own.