# Cordova Emulating/Building Android always returning Gradle Error

Tags: java, android, cordova, gradle

I am currently trying to run an emulator on Android on my Mac PC through Cordova. But it seems like I always get issue and it always comes down to Java Environment possibly not being correct. When I try to do either a build or a emulate, I get the following error:

```
Error: /cordova_app_directory/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error 
output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '9.0.1'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

I have gone through multiple ways of trying to fix this. This includes updating java development enviroment (which its 10.0.1) and also update Gradle (which is 4.4). I also tried removing and re-adding the platform back in but it doesn't work.

Does anyone have any idea of what could be causing this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not determine java version from '9.0.1'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46893768/could-not-determine-java-version-from-9-0-1)

Comment: try to `update-alternatives` for java

Comment: I have tried that solution and no success.